# Move particular year files from one document library to another using powershell script

Tags: sharepoint-designer, powershell, document-library, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem

I have two document library.in one document library no folders are there.2021-2022,2022-2023 documents are there.One year(date and time) column is there.Using group by i separated documents(2021-2022,2022-2023).Another one document library is empty.From first library i have to move 2022-2023 documents to second document library using powershell script.How to do?
i am using sharepoint 2016 onpremise.

Answer (score 0):

**OOTB Way**

If it's not one time job and you want it as automatic process then you can utilize **[Information Management Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/information-management-policy-planning)** feature in SharePoint which can do your job.

[image]

Here are some reference links for configuring retention in document library

1. https://sharepointmaven.com/set-retention-deletion-policies-files-folders-sharepoint/
2. https://joannecklein.com/2016/12/01/move-that-document/ (Read Point#7)

**Using PowerShell Script**

If you want to perform this operation for one time only then you can go with PowerShell approach as well. Following is the reference link for that

https://spandcrm.com/2018/11/12/sharepoint-2013-powershell-script-to-move-all-documents-between-libraries/